# Display checkbox Data value from database using mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I need to create a form to register.

the example of form will look like this

[image]

how do I display the value in the red circle in the form? (the value is from database)

My controller

```
namespace Insurance.Controllers
{
    public class FlexiPAController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /FlexiPA/

        public ActionResult RegisterFlexiPA()
        {


            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult  RegisterFire()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult RegisterMotor()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel

```
namespace Insurance.ViewModels
{ 
    public class RegisterInfoPA
    {
        public register reg { get; set; }
        public infoPA infoFlexiPA { get; set; }
        public personalInfo pinfo { get; set; }
        public List<maritalInfo> minfo { get; set; }
        public childInfo cInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

   <!--TITLE-->
    <div class="editor-label">
        Title
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.reg.title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.reg.title)
    </div>
    <!--NAME-->
    <div class="editor-label">
        Name
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.reg.registerNm)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.reg.registerNm)
    </div>

    <!--IC NO-->
    <div class="editor-label">
        IC No
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.reg.identityNo)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.reg.identityNo)
    </div>

        <!--GENDER-->
<div class="editor-label">
    Gender
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.pinfo.gender)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.pinfo.gender)
</div>
```

> ```
>     <!--Marital Status-->
>     <div class="editor-label">
>         **Marital Status**
>     </div>
>     <div class="editor-field">     
>     </div>
> ```
>
> **Wanted to make the checkbox here for marital status eg :single,widowed,married**

I am new to mvc, really appreciate your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
Let's try one controller first

**Your Controller**

```
namespace Insurance.Controllers
{
public class FlexiPAController : Controller
{
//
// GET: /FlexiPA/

DATABASENAME db = new DATABSENAME (); //ESTABLISHING CONNECTION TO DATABASE
public ActionResult RegisterFlexiPA()
{
        using (var dataBase = new DATABASENAME ())
        {
            var model = new RegisterInfoPA()
            {
                minfo = dataBase.maritalInfoes.ToList(),
                //IF YOU WISH TO ADD MORE                   

            };
            return View(model);
        }     
}
```

**Your ViewModel**

change you marital info to IEnurumerable instead of List

```
 public IEnumerable<maritalInfo> minfo { get; set; }
```

**Your View**

I would like to suggest you to make radiobutton instead of checkbox, because surely you can only choose one,eg: either single or married. Thus, it is highly preferred to use radiobutton

```
        <div>
        Marital Status
        @foreach (var item in Model.minfo)
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.pinfo.maritalId, item.maritalId)@Html.Label(item.maritalStatNm)
        }
    </div>
```

This is how you display, then in the controller you just need to save it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

`@foreach(var item in Model.minfo)
{
  @Html.EditorFor(o => item)
}`

Create a partial view called maritalInfo.cshtml. Put this partial in Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates.

In the partial :

```
@model maritalInfo
<!--Marital Status Name and Value depend on your maritalInfo Model-->
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(o => Model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(o => Model.Value)     
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I did like u said, but in this line, it did not allow me to do like dis @Html.EditorFor(o => Model.item) so i changed it to @Html.EditorFor(o => Model.minfo) and I got this error  Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 56:         </div>
Line 57:         <div class="editor-field">
Line 58:      @foreach (var item in Model.minfo)
Line 59:      {
Line 60:         @Html.EditorFor(o => Model.minfo)

Comment: Sorry for the code, I correct it. Use @Html.EditorFor(o => item)

Comment: Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 56:     </div>
Line 57:     <div class="editor-field">
Line 58: @foreach (var item in Model.minfo)
Line 59: {
Line 60:     @Html.EditorFor(o =>item)

Comment: still getting like the above error. i dont know why. IS there anything about the connection to database coz it is always nullreferenceException

Comment: Sure, in the controller, you need to bind your model and give it to the view (like this : `RegisterInfoPa model = yourDbCnx.RegisterInfoPa.Find(id); Return View(model)`. Replace List<maritalInfo> by IEnumerable<maritalInfo>